# Android header, footer , content

Tags: android

I have app bar , navigation drawer, back button in the header.
By default there is a grid view in the content. (which has a separate functionality with the grid view icons)
I have 4 icons in the bottom, which I have to keep it as a footer for all the activities.
Whenever I click any one of the footer icon, the content should change. And the title of the header should change. 
What is the best approach for this solution. Do I need to use fragments for the content, or is there any other easy option? Please help me, I am new to android development.

Comment: Yes. You can make the bottom footer part as a fragment and re-use it everytime you need it (in this case, when every activity is created by `onCreate()`).

Comment: Thank you. Can I use header as fragment too? Is there a way to change the title for header in each activity?

Comment: "header" you are talking about is probably `ActionBar` in Android. Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)